# What does the rt() function in R generates?

Tags: simulation, distribution, t-test

At first, I thought I understood what will the `rt()` function in R generate - I thought it generates random `t-values`from the specified t-distribution.

For example, this function `tdist <- rt(10000,19)` generates, I interpreted, **10,000** t-values from a t-distribution that based on n=20 (df=19), with mean=0 and standard deviation=1.

Is that the case, **or** does it generate `average scores (means)` that are to be found under the specified t-distribution?

If the latter is the case, how can I generate from a t-distribution 10,000 times a n=20 sample with specifications mean=0, sd=1?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you think it is not generating 10K samples or t-distribution? Any reason to question that?

Comment: And it would be nice to state your system (Windows, Linux), R version etc. Maybe there is some installation specific problem

Comment: Simple, because I am a beginner and am not sure entirely about the output of these functions. I use OS X 10.15.6 with RStudio 1.2.5042 and R 3.6.3.

Comment: I am a beginner and am not sure entirely about the output of these functions. I use OS X 10.15.6 with RStudio 1.2.5042 and R 3.6.3. ```rt()```generates values from a t-distribution, what exactly. I assume these are values and not average scores. I still don't understand the elements of the function: ```n``` is the number of observations to be drawn and ```df```is the number of degrees of freedom associated with a t-distribution. So, say if I want to draw ```n=20``` observations then I'd specify ```df=19```? Or do I misunderstood this? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: No, if you want 20 observation you set `n` to 20 and that is it. If you want 1000 samples, set `n` to 1000. `df` is a parameter of the t-distribution, and it is NOT related in any way to `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `rt(n, df)` generates `n` random samples from [t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) with `df` degrees of freedom.

> with mean=0 and standard deviation=1.

True about distribution mean (though sampled mean would be different), but standard deviation for t-distribution is ALWAYS not a 1, but a bit larger, equal to `sqrt(df/(df-2))`, sqrt(19/17)=1.057 in your case.

Lets put some code (MS R open 3.5.3, Win10 x64)

```
q <- rt(10000, 19)
mean(q)
```

prints

```
-0.008859063

sd(q)
```

prints

```
1.049836
```

and

```
hist(q)
```

plots

[image]

Comment: thank you. Though, I'm confused about this part still: say if I want to draw n=20 observations then I'd specify df=19?

Comment: @StanciuAdrian What degrees-of-freedom parameter has to do with number of samples from the distribution? You  could draw as many samples as you want.

Comment: @SeverinPapadeux sorry it took me a while to reply. If I want to run ```rt()``` by providing only the element  ```n``` (no of observations) I get an error message. Also the rt() function returns values and not samples.

Comment: @StanciuAdrian You cannot just ask for number of samples, you have to give distribution functions(s) (like sapling, PDF, etc) all necessary parameters to set it up. For t-distribution it requires dof parameter.

Comment: @StanciuAdrian I think you have some mental block, thinking about `n` and `df` parameters while calling `rt(n, df)` that they are somehow related, that `n` should be  equal to `df+1`. They are NOT related to each other at all, they are completely independent, `n` is number of samples you need, `df` is distribution parameter. That is is. And yes, `rt(n,df)` returns vector of sampled values

Comment: I think so too, the mental block I mean:) Now it is clear as day light, they are not related. Thanks a lot for your patience!

Comment: @StanciuAdrian You're welcome. Note, that this **R** function could sample from (generalized) t-distribution with non-integer `df` parameter. Easy to check with large number of samples (say, 100K), e.g. for df=13.5 I've got sampled sd 1.084 while distribution sd=sqrt(13.5/11.5)=1.083

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, What happened if I used a large df value? Is it like normal distribution in this case?

Comment: @jeza Yes, if df is large and going to infinity, then t-distribution will be reaching Gaussian N(0, 1). Basically, the difference between t and normal is use of sampled variance (in case of t) vs population variance (in case of normal). As soon as df->infinity, sample variance would go to population variance and t would be the same as normal

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, thanks, any idea of this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65992658/optimising-nested-for-loops-in-r?noredirect=1#comment116705896_65992658"